# Assert color value is correct or not in selenium java

Tags: java, css, selenium, css-selectors

I am using selenium using java. I am new to selenium. I have a class named connected which contains a symbol with green.I want to assert that if the symbol turned to green or not.

Here is my code:-

```
 Boolean connectionSymbolGreenValue = driver.findElement(By.className("connected")).isEnabled();
    System.out.println("Green Signal"+connectionSymbolGreenValue);
    Assert.assertTrue(connectionSymbolGreenValue);
```

I have tried this code. If condition Fails then also it is returning true.
Is there any error in my code? Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: try to get its xpath value.

Answer (score 4):

As you are trying to *identify* a class named *connected* which contains a symbol with *green* invoking `.isEnabled()` method may not solve our purpose.

### [*`.isEnabled()`*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled--)

*`.isEnabled()`* validates *if the element currently enabled or not? This will generally return `true` for everything but disabled input elements.*

### Solution

Try to identify an attribute(style) which uniquely identifies the `attribute_containing_greenness_value` of the symbol, then extract the `String` value and invoke `Assert.assertTrue()` comparing with `actual_greenness_value` as follows :

```
String connectionSymbolGreenValue = driver.findElement(By.className("connected")).getAttribute("attribute_containing_greenness_value");
System.out.println("Green Signal"+connectionSymbolGreenValue);
Assert.assertTrue(connectionSymbolGreenValue.equalsIgnoreCase("actual_greenness_value"));
```

Comment: Can I use the code of green color with RGB format in "attribute_containing_greenness_value"?

Comment: Of-coarse you need to capture the attribute which refers to the _ColorCode_ of the object of your interest. If that is in _RGB_ format _No Issues_ . But at the end you should be asserting against a `actual_greenness_value` which should be within the limits of `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: @DebanjanB, having an attribute/class on an element doesn't guaranty that you'll have the expected color or background image.  Thus you can't assert the color by checking the presence of an attribute/class. To assert the color you need to assert a rendered style with `getCssValue` or the color of a pixel from a screenshot.